# Restrict Bootstrap Styles only for some part

Tags: apex, visualforce, bootstrap

I have a visualforce page where am having many functionalities. I have one command button on the visualforce page to get the Popup to enter values for fields on the click. Am able to show the bootstrap dialog popup. But my concern is am using bootstrap for that popup thing but bootstrap styles are applied to an overall page.

Below apex page tag am having the bootstrap styles like below,

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Is there any way to restrict bootstrap to apply only for popup?.**

Comment: This question shows little research and a search would've quickly yielded a solution. Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

You need to namespace your bootstrap in order to apply it only to a said container. [This article](https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap) provides a good explanation for that. There are also a lot of questions on Stack Overflow that can help.